# Adjusting size of tiled image

Tags: imagemagick

Consider the following `composite` command:

```
composite -dissolve 50% -tile overlay.png base.png out.png
```

This tiles `overlay.png` over `base.png`.

How can I scale the size of the image to tile before tiling, other than a separate command?

Answer (score 3):

You can do that in ImageMagick, but you need to use the convert syntax and it is more complex.

Input:

[image]

Tiling Image:

[image]

```
# read the input
# resize the tiling image and save to mpr: (in memory) format
# copy the input and tile over it with the resized tiling image
# do the dissolve
# save the output

convert lena.png \
\( tile_water.jpg -resize 50% -write mpr:tile +delete \) \
\( -clone 0 -tile mpr:tile -draw "color 0,0 reset" \) \
-define compose:args=50 -compose dissolve -composite \
lena_tiled.png
```

Result:

[image]